# How to fill remaining height of container using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I want to make a `div` fill the remaining height of a parent container. I know that there are many other similar questions around and the common `flexbox` solution to this problem is to use a column oriented `flexbox` wrapper around the content that grows to fill the height. This isn't working for me. In the image below, I'm trying to make the container of the green and pink content fill the remaining height of the parent container with red border.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.something-before {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.text-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.text-wrap>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.text-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-left {
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-right {
  background: pink;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="something-before"></div>
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <div>
      <div class="text-content">
        <div class="text-left">
          Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />
        </div>
        <div class="text-right">
          Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to start your logic inside contianer, so text-wrap need to fill the space and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` needs to be put on `.container` not `.text-wrap`. You don't even need the latter. Then if you put `flex-grow: 1` on `.text-content` it will work as expected:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.something-before {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.text-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.text-left {
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}
.text-right {
  background: pink;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="something-before"></div>
  <div class="text-content">
    <div class="text-left">
      Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
      Text<br />Text<br />Text<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just curious, why did you override height on the `.container` ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I must have left that in by mistake. It's not necessary. I updated my answer to remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add **flexibility** rules for class `.container`. Like this.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    ...
}
```

And add a `flex: 1` rule for `.text-wrap`, which will stretch your div to its full height. Like this:

```
.text-wrap {
    ...
    flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 600px;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.something-before {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.text-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}

.text-wrap > div {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
}

.text-left {
    width: 100px;
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
}

.text-right {
    background: pink;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="something-before"></div>
    <div class="text-wrap">
        <div>
            <div class="text-content">
                <div class="text-left">
                    Text<br />
                    Text<br />
                    Text<br />
                </div>
                <div class="text-right">
                    Text<br />
                    Text<br />
                    Text<br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height:100%` in `.text-wrap`

```
.text-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:100%;
}
```

Without this, `text-wrap` only takes up the space required by its content.

Comment: That causes the `.text-content` to overflow the container, because it's height is 100% of `.container`